# Dependency Properties: 'Freezing' DataBinding until user commits

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

I am trying to implement a system that would enhance WPF's DataBinding engine.

My prime concern right now is the following:

I would like to be able to 'freeze' the DependencyProperty - stop it from updating from the Model - once the user has started to input something in the UI.

Consider the following example:
I am binding a TextBox.TextProperty to some property on my ViewModel.

The user started typing inside the textbox, and the moment he starts to type, I want to prevent the ViewModel from updating the View.

Only after commiting the change, the user will see the update in the model.

I am trying to create some kind of MultiBinding using a a bool-flag which will tell me whether we need to update the GUI or not, but other than that I don't know how to continue.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by setting UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged in binding and then set the flag accordingly in the setter of bounded property. [PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) value Updates the binding source immediately as user will input any character.

> xaml

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

> ViewModel

```
    public class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool stopUpdate;

    string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        { return name;}
        set
        {
            name = value;
            stopUpdate=true;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
```

Comment: Am I missing something here? I can't seem to find the usage of the flag (we only set it, not read it) Thanks!